# Handle multiple scroll with overflow:auto

Tags: html, css

There are many popup on a page which have `overflow:auto` property

Structure is -

```
<div id="popup1">
  <div>SomeHTMLSTRUC</div>
  <div>SomeHTMLSTRUC</div>
  <ul class="scroll"></ul>
</div>
<div id="popup2">
  <div>SomeHTMLSTRUC</div>
  <div>SomeHTMLSTRUC</div>
  <ul class="scroll"></ul>
</div>
```

This ul has this class of scrolling property.
Now once if I scroll to bottom in one of the popup. How do I set scroll to top when the next time I open another popup popup?

Comment: <popup1> is not html tag, why do you use that????...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about...

Comment: editted the text now.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
document.getElementById('popup1').children[0].scrollTop = 0;
```

before the code to open the popup. This assumes that `<ul>` is the first any only immediate child of the `<div>`.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sdz8nc3j/

---

**EDIT:** With the recent update to the question making the `<ul>` the *third* child, you need to change the `[0]` to `[2]`. You could also just find the `<ul>` instead of relying on the number of children:

```
document.getElementById('popup1').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].scrollTop = 0;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sdz8nc3j/3/

---

---

I also made a jQuery version, although it doesn't really save you anything. It also searches for the `<ul>`.

```
$popup1 = $("#popup1");
$popup1.click(function(){
    $popup1.children('ul').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sdz8nc3j/1/

Comment: ul is the 3rd child. There are two divs and then this ul

Comment: @Monansh Updated. Just change `[0]` to `[2]`.

Comment: @Monansh Or search for the `<ul>`, removing any need to have a static number of children.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
document.getElementById("popup1").childNodes[2].scrollTo(0, 0);
```

This works if the UL is the third child!

jQuery version:

```
$("#popup1").find("ul").scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: @Monansh Can you use jQuery?